# How to combine columns with multiple rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that looks something similar to the following

```
Sex <- c("F", "F", "M", "M", "F")
Phenotype <- c("Control", "Experimental", "Experimental", "Control", "Control")
MOp_Amygdala <- c(10, 15, 2, 10, 8)
MOp_Thalamus <- c(11, 16, 3, 11, 9)
MOp_Cerebellum <- c(9, 14, 1, 9, 7)
MOq_Cortex <- c(8, 11, 1, 8, 6)
MOq_Striatum  <- c(6, 9 , 8, 6, 8)

df <- data.frame(Sex, Phenotype, MOp_Amygdala, MOp_Thalamus, MOp_Cerebellum, MOq_Cortex, MOq_Striatum)
```

I want to collapse all of the columns that begin with MOp into a single column called "Primary Motor Cortex".

This is what I have so far:

```
temp <- df %>% 
  unite(col="Primary_Motor_Cortex", MOp_Amygdala, MOp_Thalamus, MOp_Cerebellum)
```

Technically, this accomplishes what I wanted, but it's not very readable since all of the values for a sample went into the same cell of the data frame. Ideally, I would want each value to go into its own row with each respective Sex and Phenotype replicated.

I understand that this means that the remaining two columns, Moq_Cortex and MOq_Striatum, will have some empty cells, but I am ok with that.

Here is what I want my final output to look like. Because the column "Primary Motor Cortex" will have more rows, the other two columns will have some blank cells.

[image: desired table output]

Comment: can u also let us know what your output should look like?

Comment: Could you edit your question include your desired output (ie, a mock table)? I am a bit unclear

Comment: Try `df %>% unite(col="Primary_Motor_Cortex", starts_with("MOp"))`. See `?unite`: *...: <‘tidy-select’> Columns to unite*, look up *tidy-select* here `?dplyr_tidy_select`

Comment: Would `df %>% pivot_longer(starts_with("MOp_"), names_to = "primary_motor_cortex")` be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Adriana Thanks for editing your question, but it is still unclear - what would the "#" in "Primary motor cortex"? the sum of all the ones aggregated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_longer` (with some specifications) and `mutate`/`distinct` (this is assuming you want to sum the values in the collapsed columns):

```
df %>% pivot_longer(matches("Thal|Cort|Amy"), 
                    values_to = "primary_motor_cortex", 
                    names_to = NULL) %>%
  group_by(across(-primary_motor_cortex)) %>%
  mutate(primary_motor_cortex = sum(primary_motor_cortex)) %>%
  distinct()
```

Output

```
  Sex   Phenotype    MOp_Cerebellum MOq_Striatum primary_motor_cortex
  <chr> <chr>                 <dbl>        <dbl>                <dbl>
1 F     Control                   9            6                   29
2 F     Experimental             14            9                   42
3 M     Experimental              1            8                    6
4 M     Control                   9            6                   29
5 F     Control                   7            8                   23
```

Comment: The output from your code is exactly what I am looking for! However, running your code gives me the following errors: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `.by = c(Sex, Phenotype, starts_with("MOp_"))`. and also Caused by error in `peek_vars()`:
! `starts_with()` must be used within a *selecting* function.

Comment: @Adriana gotcha! see if the edit solves the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the desired output may be less useful than some "tidyer" solutions.
If all rows represent unique observations and we just want to aggregate "primary motor cortex" info, we may get more actionable results if we create a list column:

```
df <- df |> 
    rowwise() |> 
    mutate(primary_motor_cortex = list(pick(starts_with("MOp"))),
           .keep = "unused"
           )

df
# A tibble: 5 × 5
# Rowwise: 
  Sex   Phenotype    MOq_Cortex MOq_Striatum primary_motor_cortex
  <chr> <chr>             <dbl>        <dbl> <list>              
1 F     Control               8            6 <tibble [1 × 3]>    
2 F     Experimental         11            9 <tibble [1 × 3]>    
3 M     Experimental          1            8 <tibble [1 × 3]>    
4 M     Control               8            6 <tibble [1 × 3]>    
5 F     Control               6            8 <tibble [1 × 3]>
```

We can easily access the "primary_motor_cortex" column:

```
df$primary_motor_cortex
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  MOp_Amygdala MOp_Thalamus MOp_Cerebellum
         <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
1           10           11              9

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  MOp_Amygdala MOp_Thalamus MOp_Cerebellum
         <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
1           15           16             14

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  MOp_Amygdala MOp_Thalamus MOp_Cerebellum
         <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
1            2            3              1

[[4]]
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  MOp_Amygdala MOp_Thalamus MOp_Cerebellum
         <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
1           10           11              9

[[5]]
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  MOp_Amygdala MOp_Thalamus MOp_Cerebellum
         <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
1            8            9              7
```